# Download Drools RuleFlow files from Guvnor

Tags: drools, drools-flow

I can upload RuleFlow (.rf) files to Guvnor (both 5.1 M1 and 5.0) and execute them with rules on the server. If I want to use Guvnor as a repository, is there any way I can download the RuleFlow files into my project on the fly?

On the package level, Guvnor provides some "Information and Important URLs" which only talk about rules. I was wondering if there is any other URL which will give me the RuleFlow files? Is WebDav my only other option?

Answer (score 1):

If you add your ruleflow files to Guvnor, they will be part of the compiled package that is created when building your package.  When you use the knowledge agent to build a knowledge base from Guvnor, it will include the ruleflows as well, so you can execute these in your project.

Answer (score 0):

If you really do need the .rf file - you can use the link that the Download link/button provides (it requires an authenticated session though). Otherwise webdav can provide a URL to the file, as you guessed.